# Use of ‘had’ in Indian English

Tags: verbs, past-tense, past-perfect, auxiliary-verbs, subcontinental-english

> Soon after she encountered the experience while proceeding to New Delhi, the Thoothukudi MP  **had** tweeted, “Today at the airport a CISF officer asked me if I am an Indian, when I asked her to speak to me in Tamil or in English as I did not know Hindi. I would like to know from when being Indian is equal to knowing Hindi.”

I asked some people about use of "had" in this sentence and they said that this is an incorrect use of past perfect and it could be right in Indian English. I don't understand it. Does "had" have a different use in indian english?

Comment: I don't know about Indian English, but the choice of tense depends on context. If the tweet is mentioned as having been made _before_ some other incident, the past perfect could be acceptable.

Comment: The article is at https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/tamil-nadu/cisf-orders-enquiry-after-dmk-mp-kanimozhi-asked-are-you-indian-at-airport/article32309977.ece. It’s very awkward English. Whether it’s standard in India, I don’t know.

Comment: It's useful to distinguish between awkward and incorrect.

Comment: I've added the rest of the sentence making up the total cited utterance, because it's a bit silly for us to be pronouncing on the "validity" of the text that just ended with a full stop after "had tweeted", without including the actual text of the tweet.